# How to remove a server from Active Directory when the connection fails?

Tags: active-directory, registry, windows-server-2008, bdc

I have a server whose AD account got crazy; log on would take hours and not all DCs showed the computer account. Now it only boots if disconnected from the network. I am trying to remove it from the domain but get aa timeout or if it is connected I get an error message "A remote procedure call is already in progress for this thread". I deleted the computer account from the domain.

I tried using "netdom remove computername /force" and deleting the machine account in the registry (HKLM/security/secrets/$machine.acc) but still the server remains in the domain.

Is there a documented method to remove a server (or workstation) from a domain that is no longer available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this only happening on this one computer?  Deleting the computer account from ADUC should work.  What is running on this server (exchange? domain controller? dns?)

**Edited to add:**

I would try forcing replication between DCs.  Open ADUC.  Goto Sites/yourSite/NTDS Setting.  Right-click on the connection in the details pane, and select Replicate Now.

It's a little confusing as to whether you said the computer still shows in ADUC.  If forcing replication changes nothing, then I'm afraid you'll have to reimage this computer.

Comment: this is an IIS server, nothing else running on it. Already deleted the computer account from the BDC - It was not showing on the PDC

Answer (score 0):

On the PDC in Active Directory Users and Computers, delete the entry from the list of computers.

edit: that would be on Server 2003, but no doubt there is a corresponding tool on the 2008 server.

Comment: Computer Account is no longer on ADUC; I still cannot remove.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked...

I re-formated the server.

It did start because of domain replication issues, I guess that if I had forced replication before messing with the computer account and forcing removal this would've been solved.